# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following PL/SQL block?

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to execute the following script in sqlplus but each time it says "missing keyword". My main objective is to select a random number from column1 of a table to the variable VNM_RAND_NUMBER for each value(1 to 8) of column2. Please tell me what is wrong with the code and is there any other way for me to do this?

```
DECLARE 

vvc_sql_stmt    long;
VVC_NAME   varchar2(10) := 'asdf';
VNM_RAND_NUMBER NUMBER;
VVC_TABLE_NAME  varchar2(50);

BEGIN

VVC_TABLE_NAME := 'AK_'||VVC_NAME||'';

FOR I IN 1 .. 8
LOOP

VVC_SQL_STMT := 'SELECT COLUMN1 INTO VNM_RAND_NUMBER FROM(
SELECT * FROM '||VVC_TABLE_NAME||' WHERE column2 = '||I||'
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (VVC_SQL_STMT);

COMMIT;

dbms_output.put_line(vnm_rand_number);

END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always helpful to post the full error stack (the ORA-xxxxx error number, the line that is throwing an error, etc.).  My guess is that you really want

```
VVC_SQL_STMT := 
  'SELECT COLUMN1 ' ||
  ' FROM( ' ||
  '      SELECT * ' ||
  '        FROM ' || VVC_TABLE_NAME ||
  '       WHERE column2 = :1 ' || 
  '       ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) ' ||
  ' WHERE ROWNUM = 1';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VVC_SQL_STMT 
   INTO VNM_RAND_NUMBER 
  USING i;
```

Of course, it's generally a good idea when you're using dynamic SQL to log the statement you're about to execute somewhere before you execute it so that you can see what got constructed.  That generally makes debugging much easier.